# AppleScriptによるスクリーンセーバの起動

Tags: applescript

Automatorを用いて、スクリーンセーバを起動するアプリケーションを作成しています。
現在設定されているスクリーンセーバに起動して欲しいので、

```
tell application "System Events"
    start current screen saver
end tell
```

というコードを書きました。
このコードは[このサイト](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/activating-screen-saver-from-applescript-in-mountain-lion)を参考にしたのですが、私の環境（M2、Ventura）ではうまく動作しませんでした。

・設定Appで設定されているスクリーンセーバを起動するApple Scriptはどのように書けば良いでしょうか？
・`start screen saver "Shell"`のように`start screen saver`の後ろに続く文字列に何を指定することができるのか、知る術はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

tell application "System Events"
    start current screen saver
end tell
```

とするとどうなるでしょうか？
このスクリプトで、M1, Venturaで動くことを確認しました。

あと、気になった点は初めてこのスクリプトを動かしたときにシステムイベントの操作を許可するか？の様なダイアローグがでたので、これを許可していないと動かないかも知れません。
確認方法は`システム環境設定`->`プライバシーとセキュリティ`->`オートメーション`に`Automator`が追加されているか確認して下さい。

`start screen saver`の後ろに続く文字列は
システム環境設定->スクリーンセーバー で一覧できるスクリーンセーバーのタイトルが指定出来るようですが、スクリプト等で取得できるか？は解りません

参考までに、Apple Scriptを編集、デバッグするには、
[Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com/)というアプリが高機能で便利です。

Comment: 頂いたスクリプトをAutomatorで実行してみましたが、期待通りの動作を得ることができませんでした。`start screen saver "Drift"`に書き換えると動作したので、スクリプトに問題があるというよりはAutomatorや環境に問題があるような気がいたします。

Answer (score 1):

解決できましたので、自己回答という形で知見を残しておきます。

結論：ショートカットAppにより、ワンクリック、あるいはあらかじめ設定したショートカットキーを用いて、現在設定されているスクリーンセーバを起動することができました。

Automatorがダメそうだったので、ショートカットAppを覗いてみたのですが「スクリーンセーバを開始」というアクションが存在することが分かりました。このアクションを内蔵するショートカットを作成し、これをAppとしてDockに追加するか、ショートカットキーで実行されるように設定することで、期待の動作を得ることができました。

単にスクリーンセーバを起動するだけならば、Automatorを使うよりもショートカットAppを使う方が簡単でした。